# iOS UIKeyboardWillShowNotification triggered 3 times on custom keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, keyboard

iOS UIKeyboardWillShowNotification triggered 3 times when custom keyboard shows up;
[image: Just like the picture below:]

When I complete the first textField and change the first responder,the keyboard did't hide,but the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification are all called.And the views shake up and down.

And When I use the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, it triggered every time,so tricky!

So does anyone have good ideas?

Comment: You must have forgot to remove keyboard notifications from which you had set in other classes that is why the observers getting called multiple times.

Comment: put the code related to how you set up the Notification